# eBook to JAR format for mobile phone

Tags: conversion, java, format, ebook

Is there any way I can convert my eBooks to .jar files? Even if the "eBook" is simply a `.txt` file. ([Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) can convert between various eBook formats, including `.txt` and HTML. It has the best converter I've seen yet; it supports CSS, 'heuristics', and many more.)

Apparently, [mjsoft.nm.ru](http://www.stumbleupon.com/url/www.mjsoft.nm.ru/eindex.htm) has what I'm looking for, but it's rated as a bad website by [WOT](http://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/mjsoft.nm.ru) (malware, etc).

> **EDIT:** I just realized I could run it in a VM! Still looking for
>   solutions, though. [This page](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-79039.html)
>   seems to list another, but again, I
>   don't know the
>   credibility/trustworthiness of these
>   solutions.

I looked at [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) (v0.7.42), but it doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this [TequilaCat](http://tequilacat.org/dev/br/index-en.html) tool help you?

Quick start notes from there,

> 1. Download program archive to a PC computer running Windows or Linux+Wine,
>      unpack it and run the Shell.exe
> 2. In this shell, select your phone model, set up fonts, options and all things configurable
> 3. Add e-books from computer disk
>      (if your phone does not support reading books from phone flash card/internal memory)
> 4. Click "Create Java book"
> 5. Install JAR file (Java book) onto the phone, like any app or game,
>      run it and you'll see the book text.

There is also a [user manual](http://tequilacat.org/dev/br/help/help-en.html) reference on the same page.

Comment: TequilaCat is being blocked by avast! Antivirus.

Comment: Nevermind, I just used it in a virtual machine.